# How do you use JIT compilation to produce a C pointer callback from a captured lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, llvm, function-pointers, jit

In C++11 and later converting a lambda expression with no captured variables is very simple, but for lambdas with captured variables to do it properly requires dynamic code generation as per this guys [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88064).

Basically what I figure will have to be dynamically generate is this. (Note the code here indicates my desired semantics not any real code)

```
UserData *userdata;
api_return_value callback(api_data arg) {
    return customized_callback(arg, userdata);
}
```

And I would generate this so I can bind the dynamically generated code to a corresponding function pointer callback defined in some api

```
api_return_value (*callback) (api_data);
```

Is there a reasonably clean and portable way to go about this using something like LLVM or NativeJIT? I'm stuck using a C api with no provided user data pointer so this seems to be my only alternative.

Comment: You have control where `userdata` points to? Ie. does the C api provide passing user context to the callback?

Comment: no they assumed you’d only want one instance. The api I’m using is defined and documented in this header file https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/blob/master/libretro-common/include/libretro.h As far as I can tell none of the api functions allow this sort of functionality

Comment: The file you linked has 2700 lines. Where is the callback? How is it passed? How is it related? Please edit the question to provide all relevant information. So you are going to use global variables anyway. So what is stopping you from using `std::function<api_return_value()> func_pointer` and storing lambda in that? Please post example code. What exactly are you trying to do? How is that small code snipped you posted related to lambdas?

Comment: My bad I was in a rush when I wrote this. I tried adding more context. There isn’t a lambda function written anywhere because I’m basically planning to generate my own at runtime manually thats the whole point of the question.

Comment: You have a `c++` tag (and no `c` tag), yet you say you want a C API?  What does that mean?  If you really want C (and not C++) then change the tag and make it clear.  If you want C++, that is what `std::function` is for -- no need for JIT or anything else.

Comment: @Chris Dodd I'm using an external API I have no control over. I want to bring the lambda capturing functionality to the C API I'm interacting with because it is not parameterized over any provided user data. The only proper way to do this I can tell is through dynamic code generation. Right now I'm experimenting with using another dll to adapt the interface which is pretty much the same thing. Whether its labeled c or c++ is arbitrary really it could fit either category. I appreciate the constructive criticism though.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing JIT code generation at runtime, you can "pre-create" a pool of (extern "C") functions at compile time and manage an allocation pool of them.  Something like:

```
#define REP10(P, M)  M(P##0) M(P##1) M(P##2) M(P##3) M(P##4) M(P##5) M(P##6) M(P##7) M(P##8) M(P##9)
#define REP100(M) REP10(,M) REP10(1,M) REP10(2,M) REP10(3,M) REP10(4,M) REP10(5,M) REP10(6,M) REP10(7,M) REP10(8,M) REP10(9,M)

extern struct func_wrap_t {
    func_wrap_t              *next;
    extern "C" void          (*c_fn)();
    std::function<void()>    fn;
} func_wrap_table[];
#define FUNC_WRAP_INIT(M) { M ? func_wrap_table+M-1 : 0, func_wrap_cfunc##M },
#define FUNC_WRAP_DEF(M) extern "C" void func_wrap_cfunc##M() { func_wrap_table[M].fn(); }
REP100(FUNC_WRAP_DEF)
func_wrap_t func_wrap_table[] = { REP100(FUNC_WRAP_INIT) };
func_wrap_t *func_wrap_freelist = &func_wrap_table[99];
```

will create 100 such functions statically and link them up into a freelist.  You can then write a wrapper RAII type that allocates them from this list and returns them when finished.

Comment: I can't decide if my never having needed to do this means I'm doing it right, or doing it wrong.

Comment: @3Dave: It means you've never had to deal with a badly designed external interface you can't change...

Comment: Thanks that's a pretty slick trick and is perfect for what I'm working on. It took me a hot minute to parse what was going on though. For posterity I also had to remove the extern "C" qualification to get my compiler to stop complaining. I'm hoping this doesn't have any adverse effects though.