# Is there a way to get class object in static function other than passing it as parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

Is there a way to get the class object in a class static function other than passing it as function argument? I cannot pass it as argument or make my class singleton.

```cpp
class test{
public:
    int i=10;
    test(){}
    Static test_static_method(){
        // somehow get an object of the class to call class member.
        std::cout << classObj->i << "\n";
    }
};
```

I am trying to pass the static function to a C-API that takes in void(*)(). But I need class instance in my function to access the class data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not for static members. You can just do `test::test_static_method()`.

Comment: Correct C-API allows to pass `void* userData` to allow such thing.

Comment: Even though you can't make your class a singleton, if your code is control over the lifetime of the class objects and you know that only one object instance can make the callback at any specific time, you can solve the problem by using a non-class free function, then when the callback comes your code knows which object to forward the function to.  The answer to your specific question is "No, there is not a way."  But if you tell us more about the problem that made you think you needed to do this, there probably is an answer to that problem.

Comment: If you can't use a singleton, but have a limited pool of objects at any one time, you can use "callback pool" like I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726395/how-do-you-use-jit-compilation-to-produce-a-c-pointer-callback-from-a-captured-l/59742019#59742019).  In your case you would likely use an object pointer in the table rather than a lambda wrapper (or you could just use a lambda to hold the object pointer).

Comment: If you don't have an instance why do you want to call an instance method?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to have too many instances of your class, you can use preallocated "callback pool" -- pre-created functions that you allocate as needed for the callbacks:

```
#define REP10(P, M)  M(P##0) M(P##1) M(P##2) M(P##3) M(P##4) M(P##5) M(P##6) M(P##7) M(P##8) M(P##9)
#define REP100(M) REP10(,M) REP10(1,M) REP10(2,M) REP10(3,M) REP10(4,M) REP10(5,M) REP10(6,M) REP10(7,M) REP10(8,M) REP10(9,M)

typedef void (*callback_fn_t)(void);  // or whatever signature you need

class myclass {
    static struct callback_t {
        callback_t      *next;
        callback_fn_t   callback;
        myclass         *obj;
    } callback_table[100];
    callback_t          *my_callback;
    static callback_t   *freelist;
#define CB_FUNC_DECL(M)  static void cbfunc##M() { callback_table[M].obj->callback(); }
    REP100(CB_FUNC_DECL)

 public:
    callback_fn_t get_callback() {
        if (!my_callback) {
            if (!freelist) return nullptr;
            my_callback = freelist;
            freelist = my_callback->next;
            my_callback->obj = this; }
        return my_callback->callback;
    }
    void callback() {
        /* this non-static method is called by the callback */
    }

    myclass() : my_callback(nullptr) { }
    myclass(const myclass &a) : my_callback(nullptr) {
        // need to manually define copy
    }
    ~myclass() {
        if (my_callback) { 
            my_callback->obj = nullptr;
            my_callback->next = freelist;
            freelist = my_callback; }
    }
};

#define CB_TABLE_INIT(M) { M ? myclass::callback_table+M-1 : 0, myclass::cbfunc##M },
myclass::callback_t myclass::callback_table[100] = { REP100(CB_TABLE_INIT) };
myclass::callback_t *myclass::freelist = &myclass::callback_table[99];
```

Now if you want to use one of these objects as a callback, you call `get_callback` to get the function pointer you give to the C library, and it will call the `callback` method in your class on that object.

Answer (score 0):

** **I offer here an addition of a singleton solution although you said you can't, for future readers of this topic, who might see it helpful. Pay attention to the other solution.**

The answer to your question is "No" for a reason. Objects are unique, and any object of the same class can (and usually will) contains a different data. When you are talking about static function/members of a class, different objects of the same class, will always contain the exact same data in those static functions/members.

However, if from some reason (probably an architecture bug), you don't care which object you will access using your static function, you can either make  your class a `singleton` (which means that you'll always have only one instance of your class, and you'll always know which object data you'll use), or define an object instance static pointer in your class. Something like that:

```
class test {
public:
    int i = 10;
    test *class_obj;
    test() {
        class_obj = this; // The last object that created
    }
    Static test_static_method() {
        // somehow get an object of the class to call class member.
        std::cout << class_obj->i << "\n";
    }
};
```

#### Read about:

[Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
[C++ Singleton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Explain-Cplusplus-Singleton-design-pattern)
[Static members in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-data-members-c/)

Comment: @Jarod42 it is a pointer to the stack, or to an outside handler. Any delete operation within the DTOR might lead to UB, or will simply be a  very confusing algorithm flow.